# How do I update a datastore variable from inside a bash variable?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a variable set in a bbclass file like:

```
#some-class.bbclass
PROC ??= ""
```

In a recipe inheriting the class, I have a bash function where I modify that variable and immediately read its value. But, the value never gets updated.

```
#some-bb-file.bb
inherit some-class.bbclass

some_configure() {
    PROC=$(grep -r "Processor.*${cpu_id}" ... something)
    bbnote "PROC is ${PROC}"
}
```

I always get "PROC is " in the logs. I have tried printing the output of "(grep -r "Processor.*${cpu_id}" ... something)" and it returns a valid string. Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Datastore variables can be read from Shell using :

```
${@d.getVar('PROC')}
```

In case you have to use others operations, then switch to Python

Answer (score 0):

Usage of bitbake and shell variables in your code snippet is mixed. Your `bbnote` line should omit the curly braces to access the shell variable, i.e.:

```
bbnote "PROC is $PROC"
```

Explanation: The bitbake and local shell variables are different. If you are in the shell function, then `${PROC}` is the variable defined in `some-class.bbclass`. That variable isn't redefined when you do `PROC="foo"`. If you use `$PROC`, the shell variable defined by `PROC="foo"` is used.

And your question in the title - I'm not sure if it is possible to update datastore variable from shell. You can get and set datastore variables in Python functions (using `d.getVar` and `d.setVar`).

Answer (score -1):

I guess you missed backticks

```
PROC=`grep -r "Processor.*${cpu_id}" ... something`
bbnote "PROC is ${PROC}"
```